# Is it recommended not to marry a first cousin?

Tags: halacha, marriage, kerovim-close-relatives

If someone were offered a Shidduch with his first cousin, and she is 'right for him', should he take her, or would he have halachic or other reservations because she is his cousin?

Comment: Halachically it's not a problem, but there can be medical concerns of inbreeding.

Comment: I edited the question to depersonalize it and generalize it. As always if you don't like the edits, just [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/75676/edit) it back.

Comment: Not sure if it's legal by law, but by Torah yes.

Answer (score 3):

The question was asked of [ynet Judaism](http://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-4185757,00.html).

הרב רונן לוביץ  answered:

> מבחינת ההלכה מותר לאדם להתחתן עם בת דודו או עם בת דודתו מדרגה ראשונה,
>   וכל שכן מדרגה שנייה. ואכן, לא מעט נישואים כאלה היו בעבר, וישנם גם
>   כיום.   לפי הידע המדעי, במקרה שיש נטייה למחלות גנטיות במשפחה, נישואי
>   בני דודים עלולים להגביר את הסיכון להעביר את המחלה לילדים. לכן נראה לי
>   שכדאי לבצע בדיקות של התאמה גנטית לפני כל נישואים של קרובי משפחה.
>
> Jewish law allows a man to marry a first cousin and, even more so a
>   second cousin.   Indeed, there were few quite a few such marriages in
>   the past, and there are still today.   According to scientific
>   knowledge, where is a tendency to genetic disease in the family,
>   marriage between cousins may increase the risk of transmitting the
>   disease to children. Therefore it seems correct to make genetic tests 
>   before any marriage of relatives.

Comment: Many are of the opinion that it's appropriate to have genetic tests (at least, to some extent, i.e. Dor Yesharim) regardless of the relation of those marrying each other.

Comment: @Salmononius2 ... and I am one of the many!